# sort the data and proportion the total data with the sorted data

Tags: r

```
  df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
  timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    yesterday <- function() Sys.Date() - 1L
  yesterday()
   # [1] "if it doesn't work yesterday()-1  do it"

    df3 <- aggregate(confirmed  ~ countryName, subset(df,day == yesterday()), sum)
```

I calculated the new confirmed number for countries.

Accordingly, how do I calculate the top 3 countries that are most recently confirmed?

of these 3 countries;

How do I find out what percentage of confirmed worldwide is?

will be the comfirmed sum.

is output ;

`Day             countryName          confirmed           rate`

`2020/05/22       United State          1858687           100/1,800154`

`2020/05/22         Spain               800000            100/0,604585`

`2020/05/22         İran                386585            100/0,256556`

data are examples.

it does not reflect the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `top_n`

```
library(dplyr)
df3 %>%
    top_n(3, confirmed)%>%
    mutate(rate = 100 * confirmed/sum(confirmed))
```

---

If we do the `summarise with`dplyr`

```
df %>%
   filter(day == yesterday()) %>%
   group_by(countryName) %>%
   summarise(confirmed = sum(confirmed)) %>%
   top_n(3, confirmed) %>%
   mutate(rate = 100 * confirmed/sum(confirmed))
```